# How to make a webapp out of a python code which calls matlab functions in it

Tags: python, matlab

Is there any way to make a web-app for a Python code which consists of a part which calls Matlab function through matlab.engine??

Matlab writes this on the website:

> Limitations to MATLAB Engine API for Python:  The engine cannot start
>   or connect to MATLAB® on a remote machine.

What does this mean??

Comment: If your web app consists of Python code running on the server, and you have MATLAB installed on that same server, then MATLAB will be on the local machine as concerns Python. This quote is relevant when Python and MATLAB run on different machines.

Comment: @but installing Matlab at the server is an expensive task.  I have thought of the following alternatives:1) making a web-app and using and installing octave on the server                  2)Octave web-app using online octave